# Android Studio Bumblebee emulator problem

Tags: android-studio

[image: Android Emulator loading forever]

I'm using M1 MacBook Pro. I recently upgraded Android Studio to Android Studio Bumblebee.

When I want to run the emulator, it's just loading. I deleted virtual devices and reinstalled but the same thing happend again and again. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem, too. And I got solved.

Solution.

Preferences - Tools - Emulator - Launch in a window option try unchecked.

refer to link : https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/issues/76#issuecomment-1023563846

Have a good day.

[example image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq4Sv.png)

Comment: It's also works for me. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

I checked for "intel virtualization technology" in my PC OS BIOS and just enable it...and emulator starts working.